# Angular select ngModel not clearing after +1 selection

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, select

So, I have myself quite an odd one here

I have an app which works with data and one of the objects has a many to many relation, for which I have a Select that links to all existing objects in the DB, user can select several of them, but only one at a time, when selecting, it will display immediately on div right above

[image]

As you can see on the image, right after adding the object, it doesn't clear its value from the select box.  The oddest part is that it works fine the first time I select an object, but starts failing from then on.

I've built a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FOmYS2X5dXSD5NH2d35R?p=preview) which the exact same code (except, obviously the fact that the lists come from DB in my app)  It behaves in a similar way, only it doesn't clear the option the first time round either

The html:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2" placeholder="Add Report" readonly>
        <select class="form-control" id="field_add_reports" name="addReports" [ngModel]="whateverModel" (ngModelChange)="onChangeReport($event)">
                  <option [ngValue]="report" *ngFor="let report of reports;">
                      {{report.reportName+' '+report.reportYear+' '+report.journal?.journal_name}}</option>
         </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div *ngIf="showAlertReports" class="alert alert-danger col-md-4">
     <span jhiTranslate="form.sampleReportCreation.reportRelated"></span>
</div>
```

The Typescript:

```
onChangeReport(newObj) {
    let save = true;
    this.showAlertReports = false;
    if (this.formDTO.sample.reports.length < 4) {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.formDTO.sample.reports.length; i++) {
            if (this.formDTO.sample.reports[i].id === newObj.id) {save = false; }
        }
        if (save) {
            if (newObj.journal.id === null && newObj.journal.journal_name === 'No journal associated') {
                newObj.journal = null;
            }
            this.formDTO.sample.reports.push(newObj);
        } else {this.showAlertReports = true; }
    }
    this.whateverModel = null;
    console.log(this.whateverModel);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using event and property binding with `ngModel` like `[(ngModel)] = "whateverModel"` because you are change the model value on model change event but you are assigning the value only to the property initially.

Comment: @Niladri, yes, I've tried with `[(ngModel)]`  `(ngModel)` and `[ngModel]`, all have the same result

Comment: Do you want to clear the dropdown after selecting?

Comment: Well, not the dropdown itself, but the selected option it displays I need to have that empty, the same way I do in the plunker

Comment: But in plunker it's also showing selected. There is no empty option

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was looking on the Add Report area, I'm embarrassed now :0, anyway, the idea is for the selected option not to display on the box, yes, I will edit my question